# How to get the else condition for unsupported documents in ng-file-upload while uploading a document?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ng-file-upload

```
 <button class="bx--btn full-width" type="button" type="file" ngf-select="vm.uploadFiles($files)" ngf-multiple="true"
    ngf-allow-dir="true" ngf-pattern=".pdf,.docx,.xlsx" multiple accept=".pdf,.docx,.xlsx" ngf-max-size="50 MB"
    id="browse-RFPdoc">Upload New Documents</button>
```

For now in my Html i have been using a directives ngf-pattern to specify which format of files to be uploaded....and if i select an unsupported format it doesn't seem to be upload(yes the functionality works fine).

I need to know how can i get a else statement if im uploading an unsupported files.

I need to get a flag or an idea in this directive if im trying to upload an unsupported format of documents where can i get a else flag of ngf-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can know when user upload unsupported files by using **ngf-model-invalid="vm.invalidFiles"** to get info about all invalid files upload. These can be unsupported format or other errors.
You can then show errors in summary by access directly to vm.invalidFiles

```
<div>{{vm.invalidFiles}<div>
```

More information about validation can be found here:
https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload